# replacing values in a whole array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to ask how I can change the values in a whole NumPy array.

For example I want to change every value which is `< 1e-15` to be equal to `1e-15`.

Comment: you'll need a foreach and put an if-statement in there...

Comment: @p0rter There is no `foreach` statement in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean a numpy array, and it's pointed to by a variable `a`:

```
np.fmax(a, 1e-15, a)
```

This finds the maximum of the two values given as the first two arguments (`a` and `1e-15`) on a per-element basis, and writes the result back to the array given as the third argument, `a`.

I had a hard time finding the official docs for this function, but I found [this](http://nullege.com/codes/search/numpy.fmax).

Comment: In NumPy, I'd recommend the more efficient `numpy.fmax(a, 1e-15, a)` for this purpose.

Comment: Strange that the documentation is missing.  There apparently also is `numpy.maximum()`, which is the same except for the treatment of NaNs.  That was new to me. :)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, that's what I meant, I couldnt find such sollution, but now I know, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Purchawka: You should say that you are using NumPy next time.  NumPy is an external library, and just saying "array" could mean a lot of things – that's why people started guessing.

Answer (score 3):

If `L` is a list:

```
L[:] = [max(x, 10e-15) for x in L]
```

Comment: I wonder if it's faster than a `for i,v in enumerate...` approach for large arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean a lsit instead of an array, I'd recommend to use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [max(x, 1e-15) for x in my_list]
```

(I also assume you mean `1e-15 == 10. ** (-15)` instead of `10e-15 == 1e-14`.)

There also exist "arrays" in Python: The class `array.array` from the standard library, and NumPy arrays.

Comment: note that this solution creates a new array, doesn't update the original one

Comment: @Kos: I intended to indicate this by naming the result `new_list`, but of course it's better to state it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, but I meant an array, cause your sollution with the list I already found somewhere. I don't kow if I can connect both... Ah, and thanks for the tip to 10e-15, I didnt notice, I meant 1e-15 :)

Answer (score 2):

I like `numpy.fmax` (which was new to me), but for a possibly more generic case, I often use:

```
a[a < 1e-15] = 1e-15
```

(More generic in the sense that you can vary the condition, or that the replacement value is not equal to the comparison value.)